# How to install Chromium 57

Tags: chromium

Currently my Raspberry Pi uses Chromium 56. I'm having a hard time upgrading it to the latest version. I tried

`sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Unfortunately I got this message:

`chromium-browser is already the newest version.`

How can it be upgraded to version 57?

Comment: You say : "Currently my Raspberry Pi uses Chromium 57." and "How can it be upgraded to version 57". I suppose there is a mistake ?

Comment: Yup, corrected it now...

Answer (score 1):

First, did you update the package list before updating chromium ?
`sudo apt-get update`

Once this list is updated, your system may find newer version of the desired package, with `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

If no newer version is available, your last options would be to :
1) wait
2) build the program for sources
3) move to another browser that fit your needs, maybe `iceweasel` ?